# Deserializing an array element within an array element using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization, bing-api

My XML file looks something like this:

```
<MyXml>
<Version> 9.3.2 </Version>
<Resources>      
  <Sets>
    <ItemCollection>
       <Item>
           <Name> Name </Name>
           <Age> 66 </Age>
       </Item>
     </ItemCollection>
   </Sets>
</Resources>
```

I'm trying to get to the items within the ItemCollection, but so far, not luck at all; this is what my code looks like:

```
Stream reader = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open);
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
var items = s.Deserialize(reader) as MyClass;
```

And my objects look like:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("MyXml")]
public class MyClass
{
   [XmlElement("Version")]
   public string Version { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("Resources")]
   public List<Resources> Resources{ get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Resources
{       
   [XmlElement("Sets")]
   public List<Sets> Sets { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Sets
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "ItemCollection")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

I can get the version just fine, and the hierarchy looks fine, but Name and Age from the Item object are always null. I've tried XmlElement instead of the XmlArray, but that doesn't work either.

Any help on how to achieve this will be much appreciated!!!

**EDIT:** The example I gave was a simplification of the XML that I receive: it is actually a call to the location REST service from the BING API; the XML I get looks like the one in this URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx

and what I'm trying to put in my structures are the information within the Location 
element.

My real objects look like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Response")]
public class LocationService
{
   [XmlElement("StatusCode")]
   public string Code{ get; set; }

   [XmlElement("ResourceSets")]
   public List<ResourceSets> ResourceSets{ get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResourceSets
{       
   [XmlElement("ResourceSet")]
   public List<ResourceSet> ResourceSet { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResourceSet
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "Resources")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Location")]
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Location
{
    [XmlElement("Latitude")]
    public string Latitude{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Longitude")]
    public string Longitude{ get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully this will clarify even further what I'm trying to achieve here.

Thanks!

Comment: So you can generate that structure but not read it back?

Comment: You don't need the Serializable attribute, it's intended to use with Formatter's derived serializer (BinaryFormatter, SoapFormatter). XmlSerializer relays solely on public properties. I.e. class is serializable via XmlSerializer if and only if it is public and has accessible default constructor. And you also don't need XmlElement attributes where element name is the same as property name. Btw, did you forget the closing tag for MyXml? Because without it the XML structure is invalid.

Comment: @Dmitry Lobanov Well, thanks for all that info. The best part of asking questions is all the stuff you get to learn. And the file is just an example I put together following the structure of the real XML file.

@drachenstern: I get the XML file from a REST service call. I thought making it a simple one would help solving the problem, but I'm guessing I was way off. I'll edit the question.

Comment: my bad.. the code works fine, but my XML was a bit different.. thanks anyways guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your input file is incorrect because I believe your code works.

Here's a quick console app I wrote to test.  Name and Age are both deserialized correctly.

Note: I assume your actual xml is not missing the closing  tag, which is missing from your example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  [Serializable]
  [XmlRoot("MyXml")]
  public class MyClass
  {
    [XmlElement("Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Resources")]
    public List<Resources> Resources { get; set; }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class Resources
  {
    [XmlElement("Sets")]
    public List<Sets> Sets { get; set; }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class Sets
  {
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "ItemCollection")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class Item
  {
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string xml = 
      @"<MyXml>
         <Version> 9.3.2 </Version>
         <Resources>      
           <Sets>
             <ItemCollection>
               <Item>
                 <Name> Name </Name>
                 <Age> 66 </Age>
               </Item>
             </ItemCollection>
           </Sets>
         </Resources>
       </MyXml>";

      MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream( UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( xml ) );

      XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
      var items = s.Deserialize( str ) as MyClass;

      Console.Write( "Done" );

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @drachenstern: I edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks fof the comment.

@Chris Hogan: The XML should be fine.. I'm really surprised that the code works.. then I don't know wat's going on!! Anyways, I edited the question to give more information, hoping it can be resolved.